# Measuring the distance between latest coordinates with a fixed one in iOS showing larger distance while they are very near

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am getting inaccurate result while measuring distance between latest coordinate and some a fixed coordinate which can be done by taping on the "Set fixed location" button.

Initially the distance is 0.0 meter as no location is fixed which is the first screenshoot below. Once I tap on the "Set fix location" button, it sets the the coordinate where I am standing at the time of pressing the button and the distance is immediately started calculated which is in the second screenshoot.

When I walk around 10 meters or more and come back to the position where I took the initial fixed location coordinate, its showing me more than 7 meters distance, although it should be less than half meter. I am testing this demo app outside in an open ground.

I have pasted all my code below and could you please help me to fixed the issue? I am new in GPS location related world and please kindly let me know if I am missing anything in the code. Are there any other ways to achieve more accurate result? I have been checking many stack-overflow articles and none help me to improve in my case.

[image]

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *fixedLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *latestLocation;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fixedLocationLatitude;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fixedLocationLongitude;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latestLocationLatitude;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latestLocationLongitude;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distanceBetweenLocations;
- (IBAction)setFixLocation:(UIButton *)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //self.fixedLocation  = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:90.0 longitude:0.0]; // North pole if no location is fixed for the first time

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
    if(locations.lastObject!=nil){
        self.latestLocation = locations.lastObject;

        self.latestLocationLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", self.latestLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        self.latestLocationLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", self.latestLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }

    if(self.fixedLocation != nil && self.latestLocation != nil){
        CLLocationDistance distanceInMeter = [self.latestLocation distanceFromLocation:self.fixedLocation];

        self.distanceBetweenLocations.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",distanceInMeter] ;
    } else {
        self.distanceBetweenLocations.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f",0.0] ;
    }

}

- (IBAction)setFixLocation:(UIButton *)sender {
    if(self.locationManager.location != nil){
        self.fixedLocation = self.locationManager.location;

        self.fixedLocationLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", self.fixedLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        self.fixedLocationLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", self.fixedLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: GPS isn't exact. Being off by several meters is will within the expected error from GPS.

Comment: @rmaddy, In that case, is there any alternate way to measure the distance accurately in iOS. Your advice would be valuable for me to move to a new path.